# Detect file changes and convert the file from yaml to html continuously using dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, redoc

My dockerfile -

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN npm install -g redoc-cli

WORKDIR /data
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["redoc-cli"]
CMD []
```

Build and run command-

```
docker build -t anyname .
docker run -v $PWD:/data -t anyname bundle test.yaml
```

Using above command, I can easily convert the yaml file to html file.
But I want to write a dockerfile in such a way  that if i change anything in the yaml file then it will convert again to html. The process will be continuous.

Please suggest me. I am new in docker.

Comment: Since Docker containers have isolated filesystems, they're not good matches for "watch files" setups.  A more typical setup would be to run an HTTP server inside the container, HTTP POST the file to convert to it, and get the response that way.

Comment: @DavidMaze Could you please give me any reference or links, so that i can solve it .